# How can I clone a running gitlab to a test-server and upgrade it?

Tags: version-control, gitlab

we've been using GitLab for about a year now and are trying to find an approach to update the system.

**Environment:**
GitLab 10.1 to GitLab 11.1
installed on SLES CSB 3.1
installed with SALTSTACK (GitLab RPM)
3 Servers (Int, Qual, Live)

**Goal:**
Our goal is to duplicate (or copy) the live-system into the qual-system (both on 10.2.4). Then we want to update the qual-system to 11.4 and run our tests. If the tests are OK, we want to update the live-system.

**Question:**
What is the best way to duplicate (or copy) the live-system into the qual-system and how is it possible to update by salt, without changing the data from GitLab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether this answers your question exactly, but you will need to copy over the `/etc/gitlab/gitlab-secrets.json` file to ensure the encrypted data held in the backing database can be used on the target server.

- Ensure your target server is running the **same version of GitLab** as your source server (it's likely you won't be able to restore a backup from an older version to a server running a newer version)
- Take a full backup from your source server `gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create --trace`
- Copy the backup over to your target server
- Restore the backup with `gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:restore BACKUP=<epoch>_YYYY_MM_DD_V.V.V` *(note, not the whole backup filename, just that portion of it without extension)*

Once you have verified the server works, and you're ready to make the switch you will need to repeat the backup / restore process to make sure you picked up changes that happened since first sync (sorry, probably stating the obvious).

Consider using `sudo gitlab-ctl deploy-page up` to prevent users accessing the UI during this process (you can use `sudo gitlab-ctl deploy-page down` to restore access).

Finally, once you've migrated your installation to the new server you can perform an upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, thanks. But is it possible that 11.1 doesn't support backups from 10.2?

Comment: Yes, it is very likely that more recent versions don't support backups from older versions.  I think there may even be a check in the restore process that ensures the backup is from the same version so, as mentioned in step 1, **ensure your target server is running the same version of GitLab as your source server**.  The upgrade can happen after you've successfully migrated content to the new server.  I updated my answer to clarify this.